# Reverse proxy without URL Rewriting

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, iis, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have been asked to setup a reverse proxy but one of the requirements is that no URL Rewriting be performed.

I'm trying to wrap my head around this since to me it seems that without rewriting the urls in the pages and the headers returned by proxy subsequent links could never work.

So my question is, is it possible to setup a working proxy solution without using URL Rewriting? I was told something about path mapping, but didn't quite get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what ProxyPass is all about - mod_proxy on Apache is what you need to use for that. Describing how to use mod_proxy is being the scope here as it would be a book, but the documentation in apache site is more than enough to get you going and set up anything.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Yes, I have read up on ProxyPass before, but what would happen if you have any absolute links in javascript, headers or the content generated at all. without URL rewriting (e.g. ProxyPassReverse) I don't see how it would work.. Unless I'm missing something here..

Comment: @Phyx - maybe put some concrete examples.

Comment: Thanks, After reading through the docs some more, I was able to clear up by confusion on the difference between mod_proxy's ProxyPassReverse and mod_rewrite